# Improving Makefile performance generated from qmake

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

Our Qt 4.5 project has a root .pro file that has a SUBDIRS qmake variable.  When qmake is called on this root .pro file, it generates a Makefile that calls "qmake && make" for each sub directory.

Now the problem is that for 100+ sub folders, this takes a long time for a one liner change of an other wise up to date project to be detected. (It takes about 13 seconds, waaay to long.)  Running make at the root of the project first changes directory to all the sub dirs and runs a do nothing make, until it finds the one directory it actually needs to do work in.  (A work around at the moment is to manually cd into the folder that you know you made a code change in, and just run make.  For our eclipse environment, this is to clumsy.)

Ideally only the root .pro file should be tweaked, but I will accept answers that hacks the root Makefile as well.

Any suggestions to reduce the trivial make time would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic argument for the [recursive make considered harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) theory: Your problem is that you have dozens of single Makefiles instead of one large one. The only way around the predicament is to refactor the .pro files so that only a single Makefile is generated. I don't know enough about qmake to tell you how to do that, though, sorry.

Comment: The problem with recursive make is NOT the fact that you have many Makefiles, but the fact that when you generate those many makefiles you don't set the file dependencies correctly. That is, since you (qmake) is afraid of missing a dependency, it puts more dependencies that are needed. Therefore, the make takes too long because it is making unnecessary files.

Comment: If you write recursive Makefiles correctly, they have the same performance as your suggested method. That involves however a lot of manual indicating which file has which dependencies that could become cumbersome, but that is another issue.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Peter Miller does state in the linked paper (and makes a strong case, I think) that the additional re-parsing of the dependency tree for each sub-make invocation is a significant factor to the time make runs. And I think the OP has noted in his posts that superflous compiler runs don't seem to be his problems, but rather the "do nothing make" invocations.

Comment: It is interesting that you mentioned the recursive make problem. At work I built a non-recursive make following that paper which works beautifully. We also had Qt projects and a smart Qt developer wrote a converter from qmake .pro to gnu make .mk using only gnu make functions and we just included .pro files into the build system and it worked nicely. So yes, it is possible.

Comment: @thiton, I had read the paper and in his example, yes, there is a problem, but the problem arises from the fact that in his example, he makes the code in an incorrect way (image this: you first make executable not providing dependencies, then make objects, you obviously fail, it's no surprise. That is what he has done, in a more non-obvious way). And about rebuilding the DAG, I don't really know the performance and I have to check it myself. I did learn stuff from the paper though, like using `:=` instead of `=` (quick question, what should I use instead of `+=`?)

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin any change that smart Qt developer would like to share his .pro to .mk conversion code? ;)

Comment: That would require seeking a permission of the employer, who got all rights reserved (.